# What is another word for lightning striking?

Tags: synonyms

In the short story I'm writing, I need a synonym for striking in the sentence "A bolt of lightning ______ across the bleak and cloudy sky." I wrote shoots at first, but now I'm revising and I don't think that sounds right.

Comment: Discharged? Flared?

Comment: "Split the sky," "rent the sky," "scored the sky," "arced across the sky"...

Answer (score 2):

"Streaks", "Hurtles" or "Flashes" are good dramatic words to describe lightning.

"Forks" or "Stretches out" are nice descriptive words to describe it.

None of these mean "Strikes" however which actually means "Hits".

Answer (score -1):

Some words you could use are "streaked", "flashed", "lit up the sky", "hurtled", "flamed", although flamed isn't a very good word.

Comment: You probably contributed at the instant Anton did.  These guys are merciless on new comers.  Here, have one.